# Need help with the DLookUp function

Tags: vba

Here is my dlookup function:

> DlookUp("IsVague", "CommodityType", "Description = " & newItem)

newItem is a variable that contains "in it in list". The datatype for the description field is varchar(50).
The dlookup function is giving me an error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword "is".

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need single quotes around the value of newItem. Try:

```
DlookUp("IsVague", "CommodityType", "Description = '" & newItem & "'")
```